# Search bar for jlabels in a jpanel

Tags: java, search, text, jpanel, components

I have more jlabels in a jpanel, I have to highlight the required jlabel at run time.

-> have created a search button and text field

I want to do following things

-> User typing some text in a text field
-> User enters a search button
-> If the typed text match with the text of any jlabels in a jpanel, the particular jlabel should highlight.

I have tried jpanel's getComponent of method but it not working

Help me to create a search bar for jpanel components search

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
String userInput = "myvalue";
JPanel panel = new JPanel();

for(Component component : panel.getComponents()){
    if(component instanceof JLabel){
        JLabel label = (JLabel) component;
        if(label.getText().contains(userInput)){
            // Mark the label
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, It working. But I need to scroll the panel to the position where label  positioned. I have changed the position of a J scroll pane but it not working .